# How do i make this code recognise my input?

Tags: python

i'm new to python and i'm trying to ask the user if they want to go again for my age calculator tool. Code:

```py
while True:
    import datetime
    birth_year = int(input("What year were you born? "))
    current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
    age = current_year - birth_year
    print(f"You are {age} years old now.")
    input()
    choice = input("Do you want to go again? (yes or no) ")
if "choice" == yes:
    print("enjoy")
elif "choice" == no:
    print ("Ok, quitting now")
    quit()
else:
    print("i'll assume that means yes")
```

Comment: First, you have to get the indentation right. In most languages, improper indentation is bad form. In Python, it's invalid syntax.

Comment: What is it doing and what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime
while True:
    birth_year = int(input("What year were you born? "))
    current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
    age = current_year - birth_year
    print(f"You are {age} years old now.")
    choice = input("Do you want to go again? (yes or no) ")
    if choice == 'yes':
        print("enjoy")
    elif choice == 'no':
        print ("Ok, quitting now")
        break
    else:
        print("i'll assume that means yes")
```

You can just take everything to infinite loop and break it whenever the user writes 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you called the variable `choice` with quotes around it, making it the string `"choice"`. Instead you should check if the variable `choice` contains the string 'yes' or 'no'.
To do so we can use two operators, `==` or the `is` operator.
Here is an example:

```py
import datetime
birth_year = int(input("What year were you born? "))
current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
age = current_year - birth_year
print(f"You are {age} years old now.")
input()
choice = input("Do you want to go again? (yes or no) ")
if choice == 'yes': # Example using the `==` operator.
    print("enjoy")
elif choice is 'no': # Example using the `is` operator.
    print ("Ok, quitting now")
    exit() # This should be `exit` not `quit`.
else:
    print("i'll assume that means yes")
```

Comment: Your are missing while True statement.